# Замена первого и последнего бита в числе

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Есть число, например 14 (1110), нужно поменять местами первый и последний бит.
Тоесть на выходе получить 7(0111).
Как это сделать?

Comment: А как у вас получилось или не получилось?

Comment: Взять первый и последний бит и поменять... Надо только знать представление ваших чисел. 14 - это 1110, 00001110 (`unsigned char`) или, например, 00000000000000000000000000001110 (`unsigned int`)? Как определяется количество битов в числе?

Comment: с тем, что такое последний бит вроде проблем нет. А что такое первый бит? или он у Вас по номеру идет? Мне кажется, что Ваш "первый бит" - это первый левый не нулевой

Comment: unsigned char скорее всего.

Comment: Тогда, не 7 далеко получится.

Comment: Так как заменить тогда в 00001110 крайние?

Comment: А какие здесь крайние? Точная постановка задачи нужна.

Comment: Установить в переменной `x` бит номер n (биты нумеруются с нуля, (нулевой самый младший)) в 1 -- `x | (1ULL << n)`, сбросить его (сделать нулем) -- `x & ~(1ULL << n)`

Answer (score 5):

Например, так:

```
unsigned int chg(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n && ((n&1) == 0))
    {
        unsigned int i = -1;
        for(unsigned int m = n; m; m >>= 1, i++);
        n = (n & ~(1<<i))|1;
    }
    return n;
}
```

По сути, надо только одно - в четном числе сбросить старший бит, и младший сделать 1.

Comment: рубрика "Низкоуровнивые плюсы"

Answer (score 1):

В подобных задачах небольшой проблемой может быть **разрядность (тип) целого числа**, в котором требуется **найти старший ненулевой бит**.

Для эффективного поиска этого бита компиляторы предоставляют встроенные функции. Например, в gcc (g++) это [__builtin_clz() и __builtin_clzl()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), которые возвращают количество лидирующих *нулевых* бит для 32 и 64 разрядных чисел ([их эквиваленты для windows MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67372566/7286264)).

На их основе можно написать пару удобных макросов, возвращающих осмысленный резульат (типа `int`) для любого (`long long`, `long`, `int`, `short` и `char`) целого типа.

Первый макрос возвращает количество лидирующих нулей (в т.ч. и для числа, равного 0)

```
#define CLZ(X) ({int _n = sizeof(X); typeof(X) _x = X;                                            \
                 unsigned long long _ul = _n < sizeof(long long) ?                                \
                       (_x & ((1ULL << (_n * CHAR_BIT)) - 1)) : _x;                               \
                 _ul ? __builtin_clzl(_ul) - ((int)sizeof(long long) * CHAR_BIT - CHAR_BIT * _n)  \
                       : CHAR_BIT * _n;})
```

(**обратите внимание**, выражение вида `(1 << n) - 1` создает битовую маску из `n` единичных бит, применение которой оставляет значимыми n младших бит числа)

Второй возвращает позицию (считая с нуля) самого старшего бита, равного 1 (или -1 для числа, равного 0)

```
#define FSB(X) ({int _n = sizeof(X), _b = CLZ(X); _n * CHAR_BIT - _b - 1;})
```

(константа `CHAR_BIT` обычно определена в `<limits.h>`)

Небольшой пример

```
int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  printf("FSB(0) = %d\n", FSB(0));
  printf("FSB((char)-1) = %d\n", FSB((char)-1));
  printf("FSB(-1LL) = %d\n", FSB(-1LL));
  printf("FSB(5) = %d\n", FSB(5));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Выдает на печать

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc ttt.c -O3 -Wall
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ ./a.out
FSB(0) = -1
FSB((char)-1) = 7
FSB(-1LL) = 63
FSB(5) = 2
End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Надеюсь, описанные приемы окажутся вам полезны.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, первый бит - всегда 1 (ну если число не 0), так что для нечётных чисел ничего менять не надо. А вот для чётных - надо стереть старший бит и присобачить последнюю 1.

Работает только с беззнаковыми типами: https://ideone.com/6m12Pd

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
template <typename T> T f(T x)
{
  if (!x || x & 1)
    return x;
 
  T m = ~(T)0;
  for (; m > x; m >>= 1);
  return x ^ (m<<1) ^ m;
}
 
int main()
{
  for (unsigned x; cin >> x; )
    cout << x << ' ' << f(x) << endl;
 
  unsigned long long y = -2ULL;
  cout << y << ' ' << f(y) << endl;
 
  return 0;
}
```

Версия для Си: https://ideone.com/LNEnzc

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
#define F(T, suf) T f_##suf(T x)  \
{                                 \
  if (!x || x & 1)                \
    return x;                     \
                                  \
  T m = ~(T)0;                    \
  for (; m > x; m >>= 1);         \
  return x ^ (m<<1) ^ m;          \
}
 
F(unsigned, u)
F(unsigned long long, ull)
 
int main()
{
  unsigned x;
 
  while (scanf("%u", &x) == 1)
    printf("%u %u\n", x, f_u(x));
 
  unsigned long long y = -2LLU;
  printf("%llu %llu\n", y, f_ull(y));
 
  return 0;
}
```

И модифицированная версия на Си: https://ideone.com/DSx3I9

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
#define F(T, suf) T f_##suf(T x)  \
{                                 \
  if (!x || x & 1)                \
    return x;                     \
                                  \
  for (unsigned i=0; ; ++i)       \
    if ((x>>i) == 1)              \
      return x ^ (x>>i<<i) | 1;   \
}
 
F(unsigned, u)
F(unsigned long long, ull)
 
int main()
{
  unsigned x;
 
  while (scanf("%u", &x) == 1)
    printf("%u %u\n", x, f_u(x));
 
  unsigned long long y = -2LLU;
  printf("%llu %llu\n", y, f_ull(y));
 
  return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
0 0
1 1
2 1
3 3
4 1
7 7
8 1
9 9
10 3
14 7
12345 12345
132456 1385
18446744073709551614 9223372036854775807
```

Comment: Что-то я пропустил, когда в Си (в вопросе метка такая) завезли темплейты?

Comment: @avp, не заметил, что надо на Си. Добавил пару версий на Си.