# Побитовые операции си

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Есть код, который шифрует числа, путём перестановки первого и последнего бита в байте. Как сделать обратное действие?

```
unsigned int n = abs(atoi(arr[i]));
                //Замена бита
                if (n && ((n & 1) == 0))
                {
                    unsigned int i = -1;
                    for (unsigned int m = n; m; m >>= 1, i++);
                    n = (n & ~(1 << i)) | 1;
                }
```

Comment: Отнюдь. Вы взяли код отсюда - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1288689/195342 - но там ведь речь шла - *и вы это оговаривали, когда вас спрашивали!!!* - не о первом и последнем бите в байте! В этом варианте однозначная обратная операция невозможна - и 14, и 7 превратятся при ней в 7. Во что теперь превращать 7 *назад*? Еще раз посмотрите тот вопрос и оцените мучения в ответах :) - в то время как обмен первого и последнего битов **байта** делается в полстроки...

Comment: @Harry, Да, видимо догадки про 14 и 7 не правильные... Моя косяк... Так я сидел и пробовал эти несколько дней, всё что писали люди) Много написано сложновато, а мне осталась эта проклятая задача с битовыми операциями в курсовой... А будет хоть подсказка куда копать что-то решить её?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/235436

Comment: @КириллМалышев, си, не с++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как поменять местами первый и последний биты байта:

```
unsigned char rv(unsigned char n)
{
    return (n<<7)|(n>>7)|(n&0x7E);
}
```

Только очень уж убогое шифрование получается :) - https://ideone.com/wTKWSg

Comment: Русский текст получше шифрует) Спасибо.